# How to determine that a plane graph is an Apollonian network

Tags: graphs-and-networks

A planar graph $G$ is an [Apollonian network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_network) if it is isomorphic to $K_3$ or it contains a vertex $v$ of degree $3$ such that $G-v$   is an Apollonian network. Apollonian networks may equivalently be defined as the planar 3-trees, the maximal planar chordal graphs, the **uniquely 4-colorable planar graphs**. And **every uniquely 4-colorable planar graph is an Apollonian network**. Based on the above facts, we can count the number of 4-coloring for the graph to determine, but it should not be efficient.

For a graph G with $V (G) = \{v_1,v_2,\cdots v_n\}$, say, and a positive integer $\lambda$, the
number of different proper  $\lambda$-colorings of $G$ is denoted by $P(G; \lambda)$ and is called the chromatic polynomial of $G$. Thus, a $4$-chromatic graph $G$ is uniquely $4$-colorable if and only if $P(G; 4) = 4!$.

```
ApolloniannetworkQ[g_] := If[ChromaticPolynomial[g, 4] == 24, True, False]
g = GraphData["GoldnerHararyGraph"];
ApolloniannetworkQ[g]
```

It may not be algorithmically efficient to compute ChromaticPolynomial of a graph. I don't know if there is a good way to determine whether a plane graph is an Apollonian network.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, a graph is Apollonian if it is chordal and maximal planar. IGraph/M implements checks for these. Thus we can use

```
Needs["IGraphM`"]
apollonianQ[g_?UndirectedGraphQ] := IGChordalQ[g] && IGMaximalPlanarQ[g]
```

Let us generate a few non-isomorphic Apollonian networks on `v=8` vertices using rejection sampling:

```
v = 8;
Table[
  IGTryUntil[apollonianQ]@RandomGraph[{v, 3 v - 6}],
  100
  ] // DeleteDuplicatesBy[IGBlissCanonicalGraph]
```

Plot them as planar graphs:

```
IGLayoutPlanar /@ %
```

[image]

Comment: It's really cool.  But I'm not sure that your function IGChordalQ is very efficient   .  I was going to do it by definition of  Apollonian network, recursively, but it's probably inefficient.

Comment: @licheng It uses [`igraph_is_chordal`](https://igraph.org/c/html/latest/igraph-Structural.html#igraph_is_chordal), it should be linear in number of vertices + number of edges. The bottleneck is probably in the planarity testing with this approach. Anyway, this will certainly be vastly more efficient than anything with `ChormaticPolynomial`. Do you have an example of a graph where it runs too slowly?

Comment: Thanks for your nice explanation for the IGChordalQ.  I think your answer is nice enough. At the moment I don't have any examples to react it's not fast enough.